# Is it necessary to check for ID collisions with a 12 char random string

Tags: php

I have been handed a project that has piece of code in production that is really slowing down the entire system at peak hours.

Basically when inserting an object into the database the commit function generated a ID string consisting of 12 chars (a - z, A - Z and 0 - 9). The function checks with the central database if the ID is used or not. before inserting the object into the local database to be sync'd up to the central database later.

Is it a good idea to remove the check to the central server to take some stress away?

I know that the possibility of an ID collision is very unlikely but, I am really unsure if it is unwise.

I am using PHP but, I don't think this is language specific unless PHP handles randomness in a bad way.

Comment: https://dilbert.com/strip/2001-10-25 PS: also ensure that your check-insert is atomic, otherwise you have a race condition

Comment: The chance of a collision is infinitessimily low. There are over 10^21 different IDs.

Comment: @Barmar I realise how many possible ID's there could be, my question was more to do with is it bad practice not to perform the check. As this system scales more edges are added so that check really does have a performance impact.

Comment: It's generally considered bad practice, since even improbable events sometimes happen. But sometimes performance trumps best practices.

Answer (score 0):

How many new objects registers in your app daily? How many objects in that table?

If you have just thousands objects, the probability of duplicating id is very very small and performance matters.

In general it’s not a good practice to not check if duplication, but in your case you can do it because of performance reasons.

Answer (score 0):

No, you should not remove the ID check, for best practice.

But it still depends on what consequences failure of the system poses. If lives could be lost, then you don't want to risk it. If it is a restaurant order system, then 1 failure in a trillion may be fine.

A better option will be to put the code in a try-catch block, and catch the failure to retry. By that, you will enhance performance as well as the reliability of the system.